# Plugin: Waterwheel Image Carousel. How do I add only text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the project I use Waterwheel Image Carousel plugin. This plugin does not work when adding text. How can I make the effect to be the same as with an image, but only instead of pictures will be the text?

Example below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO3PJ.png)

If there are any other plugins that allow you to make the same carousel as in the picture?

Comment: In order to help you out, we'll need more clarity to this question. Perhaps a link to the plugin or where this plugin is coming from

Comment: a link to the plugin: https://bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel when added tex, this slider does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use slick instead, which supports any HTML elements

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Here's an example using text and a few images:
https://codepen.io/JonathanSouthern/pen/xxZMQOz

HTML

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div><img src="localimg"></div>
  <div><img src="testing_img_souce"></div>
  <div><h2>Text</h2></div>
</div>
```

JS/JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.carousel').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  dots:true,
  centerMode: true,
  });
});
```